# Does the data file have a compression mechanism?

Tags: compression, diskspace, questdb

I simulated 50 million pieces of data to view the disk space occupied by the data files. Value2 and str2 will be written every 10 times.The simulation code is as follows:

```java
while (j<=50000000) {
    sender.metric("xush").tag("tagName", "tag1").field("value1", 100).field("str1", "hello");
    if (j % 10 == 0) {
        sender.field("value2", 100).field("str2", "hello");
    }
  sender.$(beginTs);
    sender.flush();
    j++;
}
```

The file disk usage is as follows:

```
[root@idb23 2021-11-01T00]# du -hs ./*
382M    ./timestamp.d
191M    ./tagName.d
668M    ./str1.d
382M    ./str1.i
239M    ./str2.d
382M    ./str2.i
191M    ./value1.d
191M    ./value2.d
```

I have the following questions:

1. From the official doc i know that the .d file is a column_file and .k file is index_file, so what is the .i file used for?
2. It seems that null will also be appended to the column file, and it takes up as much space as integer 100?
3. The value1 is always 100 unchanged, but the column file will additionally store each piece of data? Will this design cause a waste of space? Or is my usage method wrong?
4. Questdb seems to take up much larger hard disk than other tsdb such as iotdb.Does the data file have a compression mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

QuestDB does not compress data. All values in the column take equal space, including NULL values. Compression in theory possible by using compressed File System but it is not documented. The only way to reduce the footprint would be use smaller data types and SYMBOL type for repeatable strings.

`.i` file contains offsets of variable size column - of STRING type in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in data compression is on the roadmap, but I don't think we'll have it soon. In the meanwhile, you could use ZFS with enabled compression (we don't test with ZFS regularly, but I'm not aware of any issues with it). In our tests, we got around 2.5-3x compression ratio.